# node.js query string count

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app i am getting the query string using "req.query.params,its working fine.But i want to know the no.of(count) of query string. Based on that i have to do switch case.

When i tried for: `req.query.length and req.query.size it prints undefined` .

My code:

```
app.get('/geocode', function (req, res) {
console.log("Inside 11111111=" + req.query.-------)
)};
```

Consider my url: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/geocode?level0=""&level1=""&level2""`

```
I want to get the count as "3"
```

What i have replace ------ to get the count.

Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i after a lots of google i found the way:

```
var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
console.log(Object.keys(queryObject).length);
```

The above code does the magic..

Answer (score 0):

I whould recommened to `console.log(req) and console.log(res)`.
and see if there is the result wanted inside (I think it might be in `req.body`).

If you do get 3 on all the params that is given there. You found your answer

Comment: Thanks for your value time @Dagan Bog-Computers .But req is an object ,how it will print "3" as output???Also i tried for "util.inspect" for that but nothing helps..